# Android - MediaPlayer freeze / surfaceview

Tags: android, media-player

I try to play 2 videos in loop using MediaPlayer (Android ICS) and swap them each time.

It works great but after a random time the application freeze and I get the error :

```
[SurfaceView] connect : already connected (cur=3, req=3)
setVideoSurfaceTexture failed : -22
```

Here's my code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        try {

            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource( currentPath );

            mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mPreview.getHolder());

            mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);

            mMediaPlayer.prepare();


        } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

       mp.start();
    }


    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

    try {
        mMediaPlayer.reset();

        if (mCurrentPath == mPath1)
         mCurrentPath = mPath2;
        else
         mCurrentPath = mPath1;

        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource( mCurrentPath );

        mMediaPlayer.prepare();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: What are `mCurrentPath`, `mPath1` and `mPath2`? It's probably unrelated to your problem but if they are `String`s then you shouldn't compare them using `==` in `onCompletion(...)`. Use `if (mCurrentPath.equals(mPath1))` instead.

Comment: exact :) mPath1 & 2 are strings.
 - actually the freeze occurred also without swapping videos and looping on the same video

Comment: OK, sorry I can't see anything fundamentally wrong with the rest of the code but just so you know, comparing `String`s using `==` in Java will cause problems (generally it just simply doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

The `stringA == stringB` test will cause no problems, but it will only test whether `stringA` is the same object as `stringB`.

As for the `MediaPlayer` question, I'm almost positive that the second, when `MediaPlayer` done playing a video, it destroys (but doesn't nullify) the view it used. I've no idea why that is, and it's causing me a big problem (as I can't replace the view from within my game loop's thread).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this issue do following

Set setOnErrorListener on you mediaPlayer and inside you onErorr method do following

```
mediaPlayer.setDisplay(null);
mediaPlayer.reset();
```

after this set the surfaceholder again before starting the mediaplayer

```
mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder1);
mediaPlayer.start();  in onPrepared
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `mediaPlayer.release()` but it does mean you have to set everything up again.